# How to interpret result of a linear Mixed-effect Model based on species abundance and human density?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, linear-model

I have trouble interpreting my result for my mixed-effect linear regression. I don't if the result are relevant, can someone help me?

After testing different formula for a mixed-effect linear regression using AIC, I choose this one.
M1<-lmer(A.Moveis~D.utilizador+(1|Zona),data=d). Where "A.Moveis" is the abundance of  mobile species ; "D.utilizador" is the density of humans ; and "Zona" is the factor of the different zones in the study area.

Summary M1 gave me :

```
Formula: A.Moveis ~ D.utilizador + (1 | Zona)
   Data: d

REML criterion at convergence: 234.9

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.3060 -0.7123 -0.2464  0.5910  2.5700 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Zona     (Intercept)   8.565   2.927  
 Residual             127.204  11.278  
Number of obs: 32, groups:  Zona, 4

Fixed effects:
             Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)    14.158      3.511   4.032
D.utilizador  -16.255     13.800  -1.178

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr)
D.utilizadr -0.710
```

And this table :

```
                         Dependent variable:     
                    -----------------------------
                              A.Moveis           
-------------------------------------------------
D.utilizador                   -16.255           
                              (13.800)           
                                                 
Constant                      14.158***          
                               (3.511)           
                                                 
-------------------------------------------------
Observations                     32              
Log Likelihood                -117.433           
Akaike Inf. Crit.              242.865           
Bayesian Inf. Crit.            248.728           
=================================================
Note:               *p<0.05; **p<0.01; ***p<0.001
```

The graph showed a decreasing slope, but I don’t know how to interpret the results here. Is the relation between species abundance and human density is significant? What does it mean that the constant is significant?

I also did an adonis test :

```
adonis(formula = A.Moveis ~ D.utilizador + (1/Zona), data = d,      permutations = 999, method = "gower") 

Permutation: free
Number of permutations: 999

Terms added sequentially (first to last)

             Df   SumsOfSqs  MeanSqs  F.Model      R2        Pr(>F)
D.utilizador  1    0.16368   0.16368   2.3979   0.07401      0.142
Residuals    30    2.04779   0.06826            0.92599       
Total        31   2.21147                       1.00000
```

The R2 residual is really high, I don’t know if it means that my model is not good?

Here's the graph. the second one is a prediction plot.
[image: M1 Plot]

[image: M1 perdiction plot]

**Is there a more suitable method than a mixed-effect linear regression?**

Thank you in advance for you help.

---

Thank you very much for your answer.

Indeed I don't have a lot of observation... In reality it is an analysis based on 10 years of data. But for the species data and the frequentation data to match I had to gather them by year and by area. So that makes only 32 observations...

> You can interpret the effeect size as: each 1 unit change in D.utilizador is associated with a 16.255 change in A.Moveis, in the oppostie direction.

Thank you !!

> It means that, if the intercept is atually zero, the probability of observing the data that you did observed (or data more extreme) is lower than some pre-defined threshold (often 0.05)

Ok, so it makes sense I think

> I doubt it because 4 groups is insufficient for any mixed effects model fitted with lme4 or any other frequentist mixed model package. 32 is likely to be too small also as a total sample size.

Do you know if an other model could be more efficient? Maybe a signe linear regression?

Answer (score 1):

> The graph showed a decreasing slope

This makes sense because the estimate for `D.utilizador` is negative (-16.255). Does the graph look approximately linear ? It would be a good idea to include the plot in your question.

> Is the relation between species abundance and human density is significant?

No it is not. However, p-values are not computed by the `lme4` package, because the denominator degrees of freedom can only be approximated for fixed effects in a mixed model. Thus the p-value computed from such an approximation, is itself is only an approximation, so any rule based on an arbitary cut-off, such as 0.05 is questionable.  Also, you have only 32 observations which is quite low, and is likely to be under-powered - did you do a power study prior to collecting the data so that you knew how many obserbations and groups you needed in order to detect the effect size you are interested in ? I doubt it because 4 groups is insufficient for any mixed effects model fitted with `lme4` or any other frequentist mixed model package. 32 is likely to be too small also as a total sample size.

You can interpret the effeect size as: each 1 unit change in `D.utilizador` is associated with a 16.255 change in `A.Moveis`, in the oppostie direction.

> What does it mean that the constant is significant?

It means that, **if the intercept is atually zero**, the probability of observing the data that you did observed (or data more extreme) is lower than some pre-defined threshold (often 0.05).

> The R2 residual is really high

R2 is also not well-defined for mixed models and I would recommend not using it.

Comment: @Salome Does this answer your question ? If so please consider marking it as the accepted answer. If not, please let us know why. Also, if you haven't already, please consider upvoting it